# what tool was used to make this data visualization, of thousands of loans?

Tags: data-visualization

What tool was used to make this video of data visualization(maps etc)?  Data is from kiva loans

http://vimeo.com/28413747

Answer (score 3):

The last few frames of the video have the answer around 4:36:

> Made with PHP, GD graphics library, FFMpeg, SQLite, cloud computing,
>   iMovie and caffeine.

Also, from the comments:

> It was done with PHP using GD libraries... unfortunately, it wasn't as
>   simple as just running some software to do it automatically. The
>   engineers who worked on it wrote all the code to create the images
>   then used Amazon's Elastic Cloud service to do all the rendering of
>   the frames. It was a massive amount of data to process!

If you check out http://www.kiva.org/live they appear to have some server code in place to generate visualizations of loans as they happen, so they probably just prettified it and ran it for their entire timespan of loans. The code on that page is a processing.js script.

Answer (score 0):

I recon it was [Adobe Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html) based framework for utilizing their own API (as they Wiki page would indirectly imply). You get [Kiva resources for this on GitHub](https://github.com/adam704a/kiva-dashboard/wiki). There is also a dedicated [Kiva Developers Wiki](http://developers.wiki.kiva.org/w/page/14405514/AppsAndWidgets) (check *Analyses & Visualizations*).